# Firebase: Why not just get the Blaze Plan to exceed the limit of 100 connections?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, in the blaze plan, everything is free if you dont exceed the free limits.

As they dont charge for simultanious connections, isnt it a loophole to just get the blaze plan for your hobby project, never exceeding the limits but at the same time being able to have 100.000 connections instead of the 100 connection limit in the free plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you stay beneath the free quota, there will be no charge. This is allowed within the (current) pricing model and not a loophole.

You will need to have a credit card registered to upgrade though.

Comment: The loophole is that the limit on the free plan is at 100 connections. With the blaze plan you get 100k. If I register blaze plan but dont exceed limits then I have 100k for free. Is this correct?

Comment: "If you stay beneath the free quota, there will be no charge."